# How to password protect a file using filestream and its properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, password-protection

I want to put a lock on my created file with the help of filestream and its properties. This is my code below to create and save a file on hard disk. What I want to do is create and password protect the file as soon as it is created.

```
string pass = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode().ToString("x");
DirectoryInfo x = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~//files//"));

string name = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode().ToString("f");
string path = x.ToString() + name + ".doc";

FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(fs);

string data = TextBox1.Text;
sr.WriteLine(data);

sr.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: To password protect a file, you have to encrypt the content of the file. And then you have to decrypt to load the content.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an encrypt key saved in a mysql database (in the server) and encrypt the file with this key.
Also you should create an hashed password in that mysql database.
Then you have to protect the database and your c# code.
Using PHP you can easily process the data which you'll send to your server from the program. The PHP file will make the hash from this password and will compare it with the hashed password in the mysql database. If the passwords are equal, then it will show the encrypt key in the echo command. Your program may get this encrypt key using a webbrowser in your program.
string a = webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString();  //string a is getting the source code of webpage displayed in webbrowser1

Comment: but i want this in asp.net with c# to password protect my file as i create it.

Comment: Take the time to format your answer correctly, including the code. A wall of text is not appealing.

Comment: First as @LittleBobbyTables says format your answer, that was horrible to read, and I know my comment is the same, but I have limited options in a comment.

Second, why are you talking about PHP when the question is clearly tagged as using asp.net.

Third, if you are authenticating to the database in PHP, then you're assuming server and codebase is secure. If that is the case, in ASP.net you can just store the key in the Web.config file and encrypt the section using [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) (says ASP.Net 2.0 but the information is still valid).

Comment: Forth, never assume the database they would use is MySQL (or any specific database), you are better to just say 'database' unless they specify what they are using in the question. MySQL is not necessarily the best or easiest option to use. Just because you would use MySQL, doesn't necessarily mean that it is the best option and what everyone else should be using. To the naive user, your answer could imply that MySQL is the only option for the problem.